# Create array with size given in constructor

Tags: c++, arrays, class

I'm totally new to cpp but know some python. I want to create a class which has an array as an attribute with size given in the constructor. Here is what I want to do but in python:

```
class test:
    def __init__(self,size):
        self.arr = [x for x in range(size)]
```

This is what I have in c++:

```
class Field{
public:
    int width;
    int height;
    int field[];
    Field(int _width, int _height){
        width = _width;
        height = _height;
        field = new int[width*height];
    }
};
```

But when declaring the field I need to provide a size, but the size is only given later. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare `field` as pointer:

```
int *field;
```

In your constructor, you were already doing dynamic allocation to the pointer (which is wrong with your previous array declaration):

```
field = new int[width * height];
```

Don't forget to `delete` the dynamic memory allocated in the destructor's definition.

Normal suggestion is to use C++11's arrays `#include <array>` or vectors (`#include <vector>`).

Answer (score 0):

Take field as an `int *` to point it to dynamically allocated memory.
Make sure to free it in the destructor.

Or

Better to take a vector and reserve the memory equal to `width * height` as shown in below code.

```cpp
class Field{
public:
    int width;
    int height;
    int *field;
    vector<int> v;
    Field(int _width, int _height){
        width = _width;
        height = _height;
        field = new int[width*height];
        v.reserve(width * height);
    }
    ~Field(){
        delete []Field;
    }
};
```